# Log4j watch & spring

Tags: spring, log4j

So we use log4j and want to update it at runtime.  We don't call spring's log4j filter or log4j's configure() method.  We put the log4j.properties in the root of the classpath as many articles suggested and some kind of voodoo happens that makes it get loaded.

But now, we want to add the watch thread to refresh log4j.properties at runtime.  I see configureAndWatch, and I see that spring has a timer parameter on it's log4j loading, but since our log4j is loaded so implicitly, how do i get initiate the watch thread?

Question 2 - Will the watch thread update allocated loggers?  alot of our loggers are loaded into static members.  Will they get the level change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.x/api/org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer.html) :

```
<util:list id="log4jProperties" list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <value>classpath:log4j.properties</value>
    <value>10000</value>
</util:list>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
    p:targetClass="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"
    p:targetMethod="initLogging"
    p:arguments-ref="log4jProperties" />
```

This will reload contents of `log4j.properties` every 10 seconds.

Comment: What namespace did your "p" come from?

Comment: Nevermind.  I figured out that they're just properties.  I'd never made properties atributes before.

Comment: Yep, you can just as well use good 'ol `<property>` elements if you prefer.